# Update DB column per row in per second using timer in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, timer

I have a MySql Db table.In db column there are some same type of data.I want to assign timer for different type of data.Here same type of data have same timer.For example 100,100,100 have timer1,  102,102,102 have timer2 etc.And I also want to update specific 2 column and this update will be continue in per row in per second using those assigned timer.Here is my code,

```
 void PrepareTimers(List<int> _dataValues)
 {
     foreach (int dataValue in _dataValues)
     {
        ThreadingTimer timer = new ThreadingTimer(TimerAction, dataValue, 1000, 0);

     }
 }

 void TimerAction(object flag)
 {
    string myconstring = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=alicosms;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;";
    MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(myconstring);
    string u = "UPDATED";
    mycon.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE sms_data_bankasia set flag= @flag * 2 , sendingstatus = '" + u + "' WHERE flag = @flag", mycon);
    MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@flag";
    param.Value = flag;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        
}
```

Its not working.What is the best way to do this?Any one can help me please?Any help can be great appriciated.

Comment: I want, in one second one row will be update but it update all row in one second @austin

Answer (score 0):

In order to update only single row at a time you need to add a `LIMIT 1` clause to your sql query. It will places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.

So your `SqlCommand` should be:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE sms_data_bankasia set flag= @flag * 2 , sendingstatus = '" + u + "' WHERE flag = @flag LIMIT 1", mycon);
```

Comment: It only update 1st row,but i want all row will be update and this update will be per row in per second @waqas

Comment: No it won;t update only first row but the "first" row that matches the WHERE criteria, i guess you need to add sendingstatus <> 'UPDATED' too

Comment: Sorry but it update 1 row in 1sec but this 1 updated row will shown after 4 sec where after 4 sec 4 row should be update.Can u clear me what the prob it is?sendingstatus  means?

Answer (score 0):

I think I find out my problem.The problem was in timer declaration.I set period 0 and due time 1000.For this TimerAction never call again.And also Problem in query.And that the reason for not working what I want.It should be written like,

```
ThreadingTimer timer = new ThreadingTimer(TimerAction, dataValue, 0, 1000);
```